# Filtering Dates in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Just started learning SQL and need help on the Feb 1, 2020 part.

The database has three tables for tracking horse-riding lessons:

Horse with columns:

```
ID - primary key
RegisteredName
Breed
Height
BirthDate
```

Student with columns:

```
ID - primary key
FirstName
LastName
Street
City
State
Zip
Phone
EmailAddress
```

Lesson Schedule with columns:

```
HorseID - partial primary key, foreign key references Horse(ID)
StudentID - foreign key references Student(ID)
LessonDateTime - partial primary key
```

Write a SELECT statement to create a lesson schedule for Feb 1, 2020 with the lesson date/time, student's first and last names, and the horse's registered name. Order the results in ascending order by lesson date/time, then by the horse's registered name. Make sure unassigned lesson times (student ID is NULL) appear in the results.

Hint: Perform a join on the LessonSchedule, Student, and Horse tables, matching the student IDs and horse IDs.

This is what I have; not sure of the correct way to go about it. I've tried using WHERE and AND but get an error or only all NULL first/last names in the table.

```
SELECT LessonDateTime, FirstName, LastName, RegisteredName
FROM LessonSchedule
LEFT JOIN Student ON LessonSchedule.StudentID = Student.ID
INNER JOIN Horse ON LessonSchedule.HorseID = Horse.ID
ORDER BY LessonDateTime, RegisteredName;
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Just add `WHERE DATE(LessonDateTime) = '2020-02-01'`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
I think it will work.

```
SELECT LessonDateTime, FirstName, LastName, RegisteredName
FROM LessonSchedule
LEFT JOIN Student ON LessonSchedule.StudentID = Student.ID
INNER JOIN Horse ON LessonSchedule.HorseID = Horse.ID
WHERE LessonDateTime = '2020-02-01'
ORDER BY LessonDateTime, RegisteredName;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With what Barmar said, final query should look like:

```
SELECT LessonDateTime, FirstName, LastName, RegisteredName FROM LessonSchedule LEFT JOIN Student ON LessonSchedule.StudentID = Student.ID INNER JOIN Horse ON LessonSchedule.HorseID = Horse.ID WHERE DATE(LessonDateTime) = '2020-02-01' ORDER BY LessonDateTime, RegisteredName;
```